# Python: Cell arrays comparison using minus function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations, cell-array

I have 3 cell arrays with each cell array have different sizes of array. How can I perform minus function for each of the possible combinations of cell arrays? 
For example:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[np.array([[2,2,1,2]]),np.array([[1,3]])]])
b=np.array([[np.array([[4,2,1]])]])
c=np.array([[np.array([[1,2]]),np.array([[4,3]])]])
```

The possible combination here is a-b, a-c and b-c. 
Let's say a - b:

```
a=2,2,1,2 and 1,3

b=4,2,1
```

The desired result  come with shifting windows due to different size array:

```
(2,2,1)-(4,2,1) ----> -2,0,0
(2,1,2)-(4,2,1) ----> -2,-1,1
(1,3)  -(4,2)   ----> -3,1,1
(1,3)  -(2,1)   ----> 4,-1,2
```

I would like to know how to use python create shifting window that allow me to minus my cell arrays.

Comment: I would just treat `a`, `b`,`c` as lists of arrays, or even list of lists, and iterate through the possibilities.   There's nothing to 'vectorize' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this pair of functions does what you want.  The first may need some tweaking to get the pairing of the differences right.

```
import numpy as np

def diffs(a,b):
    # collect sliding window differences
    # length of window determined by the shorter array
    # if a,b are not arrays, need to replace b[...]-a with
    # a list comprehension
    n,m=len(a),len(b)
    if n>m:
        # ensure s is the shorter
        b,a=a,b # switch
        n,m=len(a),len(b)
        # may need to correct for sign switch
    result=[]
    for i in range(0,1+m-n):
        result.append(b[i:i+n]-a)
    return result

def alldiffs(a,b):
    # collect all the differences for elements of a and b
    # a,b could be lists or arrays of arrays, or 2d arrays
    result=[]
    for aa in a:
        for bb in b:
            result.append(diffs(aa,bb))
    return result

# define the 3 arrays
# each is a list of 1d arrays

a=[np.array([2,2,1,2]),np.array([1,3])]
b=[np.array([4,2,1])]
c=[np.array([1,2]),np.array([4,3])]

# display the differences
print(alldiffs(a,b))
print(alldiffs(a,c))
print(alldiffs(b,c))
```

producing (with some pretty printing):

```
1626:~/mypy$ python stack30678737.py 
[[array([-2,  0,  0]), array([-2, -1,  1])], 
 [array([ 3, -1]), array([ 1, -2])]]

[[array([1, 0]), array([ 1, -1]), array([0, 0])], 
 [array([-2, -1]), array([-2, -2]), array([-3, -1])], 
 [array([ 0, -1])], [array([3, 0])]]

[[array([3, 0]), array([ 1, -1])], 
 [array([ 0, -1]), array([-2, -2])]]
```

Comparing my answer to yours, I wonder, are you padding your shorter arrays with 0 so the result is always 3 elements long?

Changing `a` to `a=[np.array([2,2,1,2]),np.array([0,1,3]),np.array([1,3,0])]`

produces:

```
[[array([-2,  0,  0]), array([-2, -1,  1])], 
 [array([ 4,  1, -2])], [array([ 3, -1,  1])]]
```

I suppose you could do something fancier with this inner loop:

```
for i in range(0,1+m-n):
    result.append(b[i:i+n]-a)
```

But why?  The first order of business is to get the problem specifications clear.  Speed can wait.  Besides sliding window code in image packages, there is a neat `striding` trick in `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`.  But I doubt if that will save time, especially not in small examples like this.

Comment: The length of each array are varies. I had my code in matlab but it takes longer time to run and I faced out of memory error in matlab. So I think python could probably solve this in shorter time compared to matlab. Thanks for the reply. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`sliding_window()`](https://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.sliding_window) from the [toolz library](https://toolz.readthedocs.org) to do the shifting window:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import toolz
>>> a = np.array([2,2,1,2])
>>> b = np.array([4, 2, 1])
>>> for chunk in toolz.sliding_window(b.size, a):
   ...:         print(chunk - b)
   ...:     
[-2  0  0]
[-2 -1  1]
```